# Simple block module

Tags: 6, blocks

I'm trying to create the simplest block module possible. For the start, I want it to be visible on admin blocks page.

I've read few articles and browsed drupal block API and here is my code:

```
function module_block($op = 'list', $delta = 0, $edit = array()){
    switch($op){
        case 'list':
            $blocks["delta"] = array(
                'info' => t('Admin title on list')
            );
            return $blocks;
        case 'view':
            if($delta=="delta"){
                $block['subject'] = t('Default title');
                $block['content'] = module_get_html_function();
            }
            return $block;      
    }
}
```

This code is placed in my custom drupal module in sites/default/modules and it's enabled on admin modules page. Here's what i've done:

Save module file -> Clear cache -> Enable module -> Clear cache

But! I'm not able to see this `Admin title on list` block on my admin blocks page. Can you tell me what am i doing wrong ?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is your custom modul really named "modul" or isn't this your actual code?

Comment: no, my custom module is named vegspot. Does block module function needs to have `vegspot_` prefix than ?

Comment: ok the problem was with function name, it should be `modulename_block()`, not `anything_block()` :) You've pointed this out, if you'll post an answer, i'll mark it as 'accepted'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like any hook implementation, hook_block() needs to be prefixed with the name of your module instead of `module_`. That's how Drupal finds them, by looping over every enabled module and checking if a corresponding function exists.

While not technically required, it is also strongly recommended to prefix all other functions of your module with the module name to prevent conflicts with other modules.